# Were the characters in "The Rocky Horror Picture Show" androids?

Tags: rocky-horror-picture-show

In *The Rocky Horror Picture Show*, the title song includes the lines

> Science fiction double feature
> Doctor X will build a creature
> See androids fighting Brad and Janet

Does this suggest that Frank-N-Furter, Riff Raff and Magenta were androids?

Comment: Nooo.... as far as I know those are all references to movies that used to play as late night double feature movies. Anyway Brad and Janet are human, Rocky is also human if a pieced together one, the Frank is an alien from Transylvania, same as Magneta and Riff Raff.

Comment: If anything, this would suggest to me that _Brad and Janet_ were the androids.

Comment: I always figured there was a comma in the line: "See androids fighting, Brad and Janet," as if it is a list.

Comment: @Verdan Yes, agree

Comment: I don't believe any of the mentioned films involved fighting androids. At the end of the film, Riff Raff and Magenta did take over command from Frank N Furter.

Answer (score 0):

I just watched the movie again on one of the streaming services (Hulu?) and in the final shot of Frank-n-further, he lifts his eyebrows just before Riftraff shoots him and I heard the sound of servos, which are often used to suggest mechanical movements by robots.

Comment: This has to be around 0:39s-ish. There’s a lot of weird sounds, but nothing intended to imply Frank is an Android or those are his servos. https://youtu.be/zwBsD-c_dRk

Comment: While this is interesting input, do you have any further evidence that they might've been? Confirmation from a film maker?